# how can i get date of each weekdays for this week on python?

Tags: python, django, datetime, backend, web-development-server

Lets explain it by giving a example:
Lets say im going to create a shopping website, and i want to show statics of
the items sold for this week. like:

**Sunday - 10 products sold
Saturday - 14 products sold
Monday - 2 products sold
....
total: 100 products sold.**

and the framework i am using (Django) requires datetime.date format for getting an item in
specified date.

I researched alot about it, but i just found codes that find
which day of week is a date, that doesnt help me or i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: How is this going to work exactly? If you only know the day is a Sunday, you need more information to determine which Sunday it is and therefore which date.

Comment: Show your models and what you have tried so far.

Comment: AlexK, i need something like datetime.date.thisweek()

dgw, i dont think you need model names, just name it "Product"